# Is it possible to use Apple remote desktop to macOS High Sierra and disable the screen on the remote station?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, remote-control

I don't know about you, but for me it seems a trivial thing to do if I were an Apple engineer. Microsoft does it perfectly.

My question is why can't I remote to a far macOS High Sierra station and don't show my work with the people sitting next to me.

Comment: There is a feature call “Curtains” that blacks out the remote screen

Comment: @Allan I am using Apple Remote Desktop through [Remote Desktop Manager](https://remotedesktopmanager.com/)

Answer (score 1):

As Allan said in a comment, Apple Remote Desktop supports this functionality with the Curtains command, so if you're using a third-party client to access your computer with the Apple Remote Desktop protocol it's up to that client to provide a way for you to activate that feature.

If you're accessing a MacBook using its built-in display, you could always simply decrease the brightness to zero. Technically the display is still active, but it's practically impossible to see in most conditions. You can also do this for an iMac, though the backlight does not dim fully. You can do this in System Preferences > Displays, if you can't send the key commands to decrease brightness.

Comment: I did decrease the brightness, but it doesn't go to completely zero brightness. Is there Apple Remote Desktop for windows?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that iMac backlights don't dim all the way; I corrected my answer. There is no official Apple Remote Desktop client for Windows. If you like Remote Desktop manager, I'd recomment reaching out to the developer and requesting that Curtain mode support be added. I'm not familiar enough with remote desktop apps for Windows to say if there are any competitors which do support this already.